# Connecting IdSrv to LDAP

Tags: single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, thinktecture-ident-server, ws-federation

I've seen samples that connect an on premises IdSrv instance to ADFS, but I can't find one that connects to a LDAP IP (AD, not ADFS).

Is there a sample or documentation somewhere on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific and describe what you are trying to connect to what? You are misusing some notions ("ldap ip (ad, not adfs)" doesn't make much sense).

Comment: sure. My customer has an active directory install (not ADFS), we want to be able to consume this active directory as an identity provider in Thinktecture (so users can authenticate with the active directory credentials).

Answer (score 0):

There is a contrib project for IdentityServer v1 [here](https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v1.Contrib/tree/master/ActiveDirectory). Maybe you can make it work in v2 (the latest stable version).

I have found an [example](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/01/11/combining-thinktecture-authorizationserver-with-windows-integrated-authentication/) of using Windows Integrated Authentication in Authorization Server which is an implementation of the OAuth2 authorization framework. It was developed after v2.

But if I were you I would try to persuade your customer to install ADFS. It should be possible. Then you can use it directly as you IdP or you can set it up with IdentityServer.